# Computing Direct Scattering Transform

Tags: nonlinear-equations, reference-request

I'm working on the Nonlinear Schrodinger equation (NLSE) in 1d:
$$i\psi _t (t,x)+ \psi _{xx} + |\psi|^2\psi = 0 \, ,$$ for $t\geq 0$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

This equation is integrable, and so similarly to the [KdV equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_scattering_transform), there is a way to solve it using the Direct and Inverse Scattering Transform.

**What I'm looking for** is an algorithm for computing the Direct Scattering Transform (DST), i.e., given $\psi(t,x)$, compute the discrete and continuous spectrum. The help could be in the form of a tutorial, a paper, pseudo-code or even an implementation.

Thank!

Comment: Have you done a literature search? What did you find?

Comment: What I've thus far found are either (a) Analytical discussions about how to compute the DST, which weren't helpful. (b) Notes about how to compute it numerically, but never a full description. I imagine that there's work about it out there, but I didn't find it.